# Image not Updating using DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, django, dom-events, dom-manipulation

I am trying to toggle between 2 images based on a condition. I am thinking to change the `src` of `img` tag.
I am able to change the `src` but on the webpage the image is not getting updated.

can someone point out where or what should be used or updated.

Here is my JS code ->

```
success: function(data){
        if(data.status == 200){
          if(data.message == "Liked"){
            document.getElementById("like_image_state_change").src="{% static 'FrontEnd1/Static_Images/CovrPage_Like_R.png' %}";

          } 
          else if(data.message == 'Like Removed'){
            document.getElementById("like_image_state_change").src="{% static 'FrontEnd1/Static_Images/CovrPage_Like_W.png' %}";
            console.log(document.getElementById("like_image_state_change"));
          }
        }
        else{
          console.log('wrong');
        }
      }
    });
```

Here when I console the document.getElementById in 'like Removed' I could see the updated `src` for the Image but the Image is still the same on the webpage.

PS -> The backend I am using is DJango. (if it matters)

Comment: Either your image is cached path with the wrong one or you have more than one element on the page with the same id.

Comment: Absolutely man. I just realized that I have more than one element with same class. Thanks mate

Comment: Multiple elements with the same class should be fine; classes are meant to be used for groups of elements. But you're not referencing anything by class here anyway.

Comment: Yes I got your point. actually I was rendering multiple posts using the django template and used ID. but I will change it to class. Thanks anyway.